# Invalid argument in cudaMemcpy3D using width in bytes?

Tags: cuda

I've made a simple texture3D test and found a strange behavior when copying data to device. The function cudaMemcpy3D return an 'invalid argument'.

I found the problem is related with cudaExtent. **According to the CUDA Toolkit Reference Manual 4.0**, cudaExtent Parameters are as follow:

- w - **Width in bytes**
- h - Height in elements
- d - Depth in elements

So, I prepared the texture as follows:

```
// prepare texture 
cudaChannelFormatDesc t_desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<baseType>();
// CUDA extent parameters w - Width in bytes, h - Height in elements, d - Depth in elements
cudaExtent t_extent = make_cudaExtent(NCOLS*sizeof(baseType), NROWS, DEPTH);
// CUDA arrays are opaque memory layouts optimized for texture fetching
cudaArray *i_ArrayPtr = NULL;
// allocate 3D
status = cudaMalloc3DArray(&i_ArrayPtr, &t_desc, t_extent);
```

And configured the 3D parameters as follow:

```
// prepare input data
cudaMemcpy3DParms i_3DParms = { 0 };
i_3DParms.srcPtr   = make_cudaPitchedPtr( (void*)h_idata, NCOLS*sizeof(baseType), NCOLS, NROWS);
i_3DParms.dstArray = i_ArrayPtr;
i_3DParms.extent   = t_extent;
i_3DParms.kind     = cudaMemcpyHostToDevice;
```

And finally copied the data to device memory:

```
// copy input data from host to device
status = cudaMemcpy3D( &i_3DParms );
```

The problem is solved if I **only specified the number of element in the x dimension** as:

```
cudaExtent t_extent = make_cudaExtent(NCOLS, NROWS, DEPTH);
```

which **does not produce any error** and the test work as expected.

I'm wondering if I miss something with the cudaExtent function or something else. *Why the width parameter is not needed to be expressed in bytes* ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For CUDA arrays, the extent is specified with the width given in array elements. For allocating linear memory, the extent is specified with the width given in bytes. Because you are allocating an array with `cudaMalloc3DArray`, use the width in elements. If you were using `cudaMalloc3D`, the extent would have a width in bytes.

Comment: That's the conclusion I come. Is documented in the reference manual, or based on your expertise?

Comment: It is documented in the API reference, but maybe not where you looked. On the `cudaMalloc3Darray` page is says "For 3D arrays, valid extent ranges are {(1, maxTexture3D[0]), (1, maxTexture3D[1]), (1, maxTexture3D[2])}". The `make_cudaExtent` documentation is a bit ambiguous because it only documents the arguments as they apply to the 3D linear case, not to the 3D array case.